# How to monitor indexing progress in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Ran indexing over 2.5 billion rows. Its around 9 hours and still nothing. I see that its keeping disk very busy. How to monitor the progress?
Thank you.

Comment: No way in practice... as a very approximate you may compare current table file size and expected one.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. I would try dba.stackexchange.com for an admin question like this one.

Comment: @TheImpaler    sorry. will do it next time.